# NextJS next-routes: How to have multiple values for same key?

Tags: javascript, next.js, router

I am wondering how could I have multiple values using nextjs routes for the same  key for example:

This is what I have now:

> http://example.com/page?colors=white?numbers=1 
>   query.colors would be a string "white"

This is what I would like to have:

> http://example.com/page?colors=white-red-blue?numbers=1-2-3 I would like query.colors to be an array holding strings like ["white", "red","blue"]

ps: I am using https://github.com/fridays/next-routes

**edit: Found this https://github.com/fridays/next-routes/issues/250**

Answer (score -2):

Only use one `?` to split into the query params. Then you can use `&` to show multiple values. Afterwards, you will have a few options on how you wish to display arrays in the url

```
.../page?colors=white&numbers=1
```